# Schedule backup in MySQL and generate compressed file

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL in Windows. I have a daily scheduled backup by MySQL Administrator that generates a .sql file and put it in a dropbox folder.

I want to put in the dropbox folder this file compressed. How can I do that ?